# Freeswitch: play ringing tone to A-leg, while we play some message to called party B-leg

Tags: voip, freeswitch

In asterisk dial command `A(x): Play an announcement (x.gsm) to the called party.` is available to play some message to b-leg and still keep a-leg hear ringing tone.

In freeswitch i tried

`_nolocal_execute_on_answer=playback <file>`

and

`bridge_pre_execute_bleg_app=playback
bridge_pre_execute_bleg_data=<file>`

I get initial ringtone before bridge. But then after b-leg asnwer, A-leg gets only silent audio until the audio file gets completed on B-leg. How do i make it such that A-leg still gets ring tone, while there is a message being played only to B-leg? Your suggestion might help me a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`group_confirm_file` is the best option for playing a message to callee before bridging the call to A leg

`<action application="set" data="group_confirm_file=playback /path/to/prompt.wav"/>
 <action application="set" data="group_confirm_key=exec"/>`

Reference: [FS-jira](https://freeswitch.org/jira/browse/FS-9558#add-comment) and [FS-wiki](https://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Freeswitch_IVR_Originate#Answer_confirmation)

Answer (score 0):

the best way is to use some ESL programming to handle two independent call legs, and then bridging them together when B party answers.

Here I have an example that models a similar scenario: 
https://github.com/xlab1/go-fs-secretary-prototype

https://github.com/xlab1/go-fs-secretary-prototype/blob/master/golang/secretary_server.go

Lines 49-53: answer A leg and play back MOH (woudl be th eringback in your case)

Line 95: make an outbound call to B leg

Line 151: play a message to B leg and wait for DTMF input

Lines 156-162: either drop the A leg, or bridge it with B leg, depending on DTMF input.

Comment: I'm not seeing where you're trying to control A-leg to play ringtone while Playback some audio on B-leg.

Comment: Thanks, Let me try this and see